# How to save your own Bevel profiles to the drop-down list (preset)?

Tags: bevel

Is it possible to save your own Bevel settings to a new preset and add them to the drop-down list? It's very boring to draw a custom bevel profile manually each time again.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be, but it's been discussed on right-click-select [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/custom-bevel-profiles-user-presets-yet/1324585) and is apparently available in the paid-for HardOps addon. Tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kxfEaFo7O4&list=PL_MD6hcjgJa_Z0NpIvleE2IF3hzQc0INb&index=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER:** Blender doesn't have this possibility
VOTE FOR THIS FEATURE HERE: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/2W5M/

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you cant (yet). As a workaround, you can save your custom profile into a bevel modifier. Add a dummy object where you can add a bevel modifier, give it an appropiate profile name,  and select `Profile > Custom` to have a place for your profile ready. If you hover over a profile (either in the settings menu or in the modifier menu) you can `Ctrl+C` / `Ctrl+V` to copy the profiles around.